# Perl6, how to remove the last character in a string?

Tags: raku

In Perl6, how does one remove the last character from a string?

Comment: For those who are more familiar with method calls, this is a little bit more verbose but perhaps easier to remember:
`perl6 -e 'my $x="a b c d "; $x.=subst(/" "$/, ""); say "<$x>";'`

Comment: [`chop`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/chop)

Answer (score 6):

My `Perl6` notes on how to remove the last letter of a string:

```
$ perl6 -e 'my $x="a b c d "; $x = chop( $x ); say "<$x>";'
<a b c d>

 $ perl6 -e 'my $x="a b c d "; $x ~~ s/" "$//; say "<$x>";'
<a b c d>
```

Note `$` means to match at the end of the string

Comment: `perl6 -e 'say "a b c d".chop'`

Comment: please note that the second piece of code will not "remove the last letter of a string"; it will only remove a single space at the very end of the string. For the other thing, replace `" "` with just `.`

Comment: if the intent is to remove the white space: `perl6 -e 'my $x="a b c d "; say ">{$x.trim}<";'`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way you can do it with `substr`:

```
$ perl6 -e 'my $a := "abcde"; say $a.substr(0, *-1)'
abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

chop will take the last character off a string, however sometimes you want to remove the line terminator so you would rather use chomp:

```
my @s = "hello world", "hello world\n", "hello world\r", "hello world\r\n" ;
my $ct = 0 ;
for @s -> $str {
    say "run ", $ct++ ;
    my $s1 =$str ;
    my $s2 =$str ;
    say "orig >",$str,"<" ;
    say "chop >",$s1.chop,"<" ;
    say "chomp >",$s2.chomp,"<" ;
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./run.p6 
run 0
orig >hello world<
chop >hello worl<
chomp >hello world<
run 1
orig >hello world
<
chop >hello world<
chomp >hello world<
run 2
<rig >hello world
chop >hello world<
chomp >hello world<
run 3
orig >hello world
<
chop >hello world<
chomp >hello world<
```